# An error occurred when attaching the database(s). Click the hyperlink in the Message column for details

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

i am trying to attach external database named ( HaseebProject.mdf) but every time i got an error
" An error occurred when attaching the database(s).  Click the hyperlink in the Message column for details."
What'sthe error is there..?? even there is any error message in message field as shown.

[image]

When i click on add button to add database there are two paths in directory for database. i have tried with both but he same error.

[image]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try running SQL Server Management Studio as administrator

Comment: This did not work for me.  This doesn't seem to work if the mdf file is in a shared folder from a host machine.

Comment: This worked for me. Maybe you have corrupt the .mdf file?

Comment: This worked for me. Sometimes it's the simplest of reasons.

Answer (score 14):

All of the answers I've seen so far are possible suggestions of what could be the issue, but it doesn't necessarily help you identify the issue that's preventing you from attaching this database.

The error message you are referring to is actually pointing you to a more specific error message for your case. This more specific error message is located in the Message column of the "Attach Database" window that you've already opened (you may just need to scroll to the right of the "Databases to attach" section and click on the message to see it in its entirety.

[image: See circled area]

Comment: I agree with what Ryan Harris has written in the comment. In my case the error was that the database I was trying to attach already existed. Then I used a `.bak` file and restored the database. It worked.

Comment: Thanks! This helped my solve my error on the .mdf file being compressed by Windows. Check my answer below.

Comment: The most helpful answer. My issue was that log files were located in the next folder, not the same one

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem as well, I did right click on (`.mdf` and `.ldf`) the file then on the security tab, click on Edit.

In a new window find the users and set permission to full control. If you can't find users click on:

```
add button-->advanced-->Find now-->find users
```

and then click on Ok.
if it doesn't work you can backup from your database and restore it instead of attaching. I have done it and it works.But before restoring make sure that your DB (.mdf and .ldf) shouldn't  exist in SQL server database directory before restoring (it's up to your SQL server installation path in my case -->C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQL2014\MSSQL\DATA)  otherwise you will face to an error

Comment: in my case the user was added... I only had to give Full Control permissions. Now it is working

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to the directory containing the database and open the
   properties for the folder.
2. Go to the Security tab, Edit permissions, Add User.
3. In Locations, select the location that is hosting the server.
4. In object names, Enter `NT Service\MSSQL$<Instance-Name>` (e.g. `NT
   Service\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER`).
5. Set Permissions to full control and save.

This will give your SQL Server instance full permissions for the target directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the `MyDataBase.MDF` file
2. Select Properties -> Go to Security tab -> Select Edit -> Select Add -> Select Advanced -> Select Find Now -> Selecte User Administrator & User Everyone
3. Set permissions to full control for both
4. Click OK
5. Clear `MyDataBase_log.LDF` file
6. Copy `MyDataBase.MDF` file to this location:

   `(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA)`
7. Run SQL Server Management Studio as an administrator
8. Attach MyDataBase.MDF file from this address:

   `(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA)`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I changed the main database file names so I had to select them again using button in "Current File Path" column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a **database with the same name**, delete it before you try to attach the .mdf file. My issue was that they were named the same.

Ryan Harris mentioned looking at the error message, this helped me a lot. So look at that first, you might have a different issue.

[SQL message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJFS1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was the disk which I was transferring the database file. So if you are copying the database file from one computer to another computer make sure the removable disk is not corrupted. Always try a second removable disk. And also don't forget to run SSMS as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to attache db from .mdf file

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [SchoolDB] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\SchoolDB.mdf' )
FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After I expanded the error message, I found that it was saying the .MDF file was compressed.

I googled the issue and found this resource that solved my issue.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2006/10/02/sql-server-databases-are-not-supported-on-compressed-volumes/

If your error is similar to this:

```
Create failed for Database 'Compressed_DB'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

The file "E:Compressed_DB.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.

CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5118)
```

Then you can right click the folder in which the .MDF file resides, click "Properties".
Click "Advanced" in the General tab, and uncheck "Compress contents to save disk space"

This solved the error I was getting, so try it out and attach your .MDF again.

Comment: What do you mean "After I expanded the error message"?  There doesn't seem to be anything to expand.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:- Just give permission to database folder and attached mdf file then.

Answer (score 0):

check version of the sql server software and the sql software that mdf was created. must be the same versions.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX1qC.png)

you should be accept allow security MDFfile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).